# SymmetricDS messes up with tripple foreign key

Tags: mysql, jdbc, symmetricds

I have a database which is supposed to be synchronized using SymmetricDS. There are following queries, building the base:

```
CREATE TABLE `defectstdreference` (
  `std_doc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Идентификатор НТД',
  `improve_notice_doc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Идентификатор предписания',
  `defect_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Идентификатор дефекта',
  `paragraph` varchar(4000) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Пункт НТД',
  `reference_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Идентификатор ссылки на пункт НТД',
  `client_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reference_id`),
  KEY `Relationship70` (`std_doc_id`),
  KEY `Relationship72` (`improve_notice_doc_id`,`defect_id`,`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Relationship70` FOREIGN KEY (`std_doc_id`) REFERENCES `std` (`doc_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Relationship72` FOREIGN KEY (`improve_notice_doc_id`, `defect_id`, `client_id`) REFERENCES `improvementnoticedefect` (`doc_id`, `defect_id`, `client_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Ссылки на НТД выявленных нарушений';
```

and the table which is referenced:

```
CREATE TABLE `improvementnoticedefect` (
  `description` varchar(20000) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Описание нарушения',
  `defect_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Номер нарушения в рамках предписания',
  `doc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Номер документа "Предписание"',
  `client_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`doc_id`,`defect_id`,`client_id`),
  KEY `Relationship68` (`doc_id`,`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Relationship68` FOREIGN KEY (`doc_id`, `client_id`) REFERENCES `improvementnotice` (`doc_id`, `client_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Дефект';
```

As you can see, the order of columns in primary key of table `impovementnoticedefect` and in fk constraint 72 of `defectstdreference` are the same.

Yet, when the synchronization is started, SymmetricDS gives me the error:

```
Cannot add foreign key constraint.  Failed to execute: ALTER TABLE `defectstdreference`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `Relationship72` FOREIGN KEY (`improve_notice_doc_id`, `defect_id`, `client_id`) REFERENCES `improvementnoticedefect` (`doc_id`, `defect_id`, `client_id`)
```

and when I try to dump sql for the table SymmetricDS created I get the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `improvementnoticedefect` (
  `defect_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `doc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(20000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`defect_id`,`doc_id`,`client_id`),
  KEY `Relationship68` (`doc_id`,`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Relationship68` FOREIGN KEY (`doc_id`, `client_id`) REFERENCES `improvementnotice` (`doc_id`, `client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As you can see, the order of fields in primary key is different.

I tried running the erroneous query manually, and it gave an error, but when I changed the order of fields, everything was fine.

How can I fix this? Is there any configuration I should do or smth? I'm really desperate here, can anybody help?

**Update**
I have realized, that the problem is that SymmetricDS uses XML to send tables, and PK is created from XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE database SYSTEM "http://db.apache.org/torque/dtd/database">
<database name="dataextractor">
    <table name="improvementnoticedefect">
         <column name="defect_id" primaryKey="true" required="true" type="INTEGER" size="10">
             <platform-column name="mysql" type="INT" size="10"/>
         </column>
         <column name="doc_id" primaryKey="true" required="true" type="BIGINT" size="19">
             <platform-column name="mysql" type="BIGINT" size="19"/>
         </column>
         <column name="client_id" primaryKey="true" required="true" type="BIGINT" size="19">
             <platform-column name="mysql" type="BIGINT" size="19"/>
         </column>
         <column name="description" required="true" type="VARCHAR" size="20000">
             <platform-column name="mysql" type="VARCHAR" size="20000"/>
         </column>
         <foreign-key name="Relationship68" foreignTable="improvementnotice">
             <reference local="doc_id" foreign="doc_id"/>
             <reference local="client_id" foreign="client_id"/>
         </foreign-key>
     </table>
</database>
```

And you can see, that from this XML primary key is generated in order of created columns, which is actually wrong